# Rails - Using an argument as a model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, arguments, helper, argument-passing

Here's my view:

```
<%= check_box_tag :age_visible, 1, checked?(:age_visible) %>
```

This accesses the helper method:

```
def checked?(pref)
  if @user.preferences.pref == "1"
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I want the helper to state:

```
if @user.preferences.age_visible == "1"
```

so it will check the database to see if the user has previously chosen to show their age and if so the check box will be checked; otherwise, not.  Right now it simply passes false, but will pass true if I write out "@user.preferences.age_visible" in the helper.  But, of course, I want to be able to use the helper for other attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Davidb's answer is correct, but for future cases where you want to call a method dynamically, you can use `send`. E.g. like this:

```
@user.preferences.send(:age_visible)
```

Just a little tip to make your helper more concise:

```
@user.preferences.send(pref) == "1"
```

already returns a boolean, so you can rewrite your helper like this:

```
def checked?(pref)
  @user.preferences.send(pref) == "1"
end
```

Comment: @Lee, actually I think Davidb's answer below is better.

Comment: See my reply below... I'm not using separate columns for each attribute, but a preferences column using OpenStruct.

Comment: Great, I'll be updating the helper to be more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need any additional helpers. When you create a boolean field in the database ActiveRecords provides a method to query if its set to true or not. Try this:

```
<%= check_box_tag :age_visible, 1, @user.age_visible? %>
```

Comment: I'm not using a boolean field since I would have to create a separate column for each attribute I would want to toggle. Instead I have a preferences column for each user that has the information... I tested it, and @user.preferences.age_visible == "1" would work in the view, but the helper seems cleaner.